# Swagger REST API patch request to change one field of model

Tags: c#, rest, http-headers

I have a REST API setup with the following items as part of the model. It is a Card model that handles payment methods for employees of a company.
I am trying to create a patch request on the Card Controller where I would be able to just update the balance of the card. I have a put method but instead of wanting to update the full object each time I just want to update the balance field of the model with a PATCH request.

```
public class Card
{
    [Key]
    public long CardNumber { get; set; }

    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public string PinNum { get; set; }

    public string CardId { get; set; }

    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

The put method works for updating all the fields in the model but I am only aiming to update the balance. I am using swagger endpoints to see the changes working and in the swagger endpoint for the PATCH request I would want it to only show the balance field in JSON and be able to update the db with the patch change.

What is the best way to handle updating just the balance, is it a PATCH request and if so how would it be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you also need the card number to know which card balance you want to update? Unless you're routing with the ID I suppose.

You should create a DTO for the balance. Basically, you create a class called, say "CardBalanceDto", which would contain only the fields that you need from the Card model (in this case only the balance property). Then, on the API controller method for PATCH requests, simply accept a CardBalanceDto type, and then change only the balance field.

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PatchCard(long id, CardBalanceDto balanceDto)
{
    var card = new Card() { Id = id, Balance = balanceDto.Balance};
    _context.Cards.Attach(Card);
    _context.Entry(card).Property(x => x.Balance).IsModified = true;

    return Ok(await _context.SaveChangesAsync());
}
```

Your DTO would look something like this:

```
public class CardBalanceDto {
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Appreciatae the reply, I am now looking at DTO's but could you offer some insight towards how I would be able to implement the CardBalanceDto into a patch request? As I am not sure how to "simply accept a CardBalanceDto type, and then change only the balance field."

Comment: Are you scaffolding your API controllers with Visual Studio? In any case, your patch method will have an argument of type Card, simply change that argument to CardBalanceDto. Then use entity framework to change the balance.

Comment: Thanks for the support! Yes been scaffoling the controllers in VS, works perfect as intended now.